# Number of different minimum spanning trees in the graph

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Let $G$ be a complete graph with $2n\ge6$ vertices. All edges in the graph have weights $2$, except the edges in the following cycles
$$v_1,v_2,...,v_n,v_1,  \qquad v_{n+1},v_{n+2},...,v_{2n},v_{n+1}$$
which all have weights equal to $1$. According to Cayley's formula, the total number of spanning trees in this graph is equal to $(2n)^{2n-2}$. I would like to know if there also is a simple way to find the total number of *minimum* spanning trees in the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is incorrect, please tell me and I will delete.

In this new graph, the MST will have total edge weight $2n$, consisting of $(2n - 2)$ 1-edge and $1$ 2-edge. This is possible for example by taking $v_1 \to v_2 \to \ldots \to v_{2n}$. Clearly, it is impossible to do better, since the graph with only edges of weight $1$ is disconnected.

Now we can separate our MST into the $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ part, the $\{v_{n + 1}, v_{n + 2}, \ldots, v_{2n}\}$ part, and a single 2-edge connecting the two parts. Now we can count the number of MST in each of the two parts, which are both $n$, since such MST must only consist of edges of weight $1$. We then connect them with a single edge, which has $n^2$ choices. Therefore, in $G$ we have $n^4$ MST.

Comment: You write that the number of spanning trees in $n$ vertices in either of the two parts of the graph is $n^{n-1}$, but that is only if we allow to take paths of weight equal to $2$. In that case, we are no longer only counting the number of minimum spanning trees.

Comment: @Hydrogen Oh wait I think I misread the question. So only the edges on the *cycle* $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ have weight 1? If so, there are only $n$ MST in each part, and the final answer is $n^4$. See if you agree with me :)

Comment: No the edges in both cycles have weight $1$, and all other edges have weight $2$.

Comment: @Hydrogen Then what's wrong with my answer? There are only $n$ MST in the graph induced by $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ and $\{v_{n + 1}, v_{n + 2}, \ldots, v_{n + 2}\}$, since for a spanning tree to be minimum it must *only* consist of weight 1 edge, which means the whole tree lies on the cycle, for which there are only $n$ MST (each by removing a single edge from the cycle).

Comment: But you write "Now we can count the number of spanning trees in $n$ vertices in the two parts, which are both $n^{n−1}$". So it seems you use Cayley's formula on the subgraph of vertices $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ and on the subgraph with vertices $v_{n+1},v_{n+2},v_{2n}$. But Cayley's formula can only be used on a complete graph, which means that $n^{n-1}$ is the number of spanning trees in each subgraph if we do not consider the weights of the edges.

Comment: @Hydrogen Yeah, I will edit my answer now. The correct solution should be $n\cdot n\cdot n^2$.

Comment: @Hydrogen if this helped feel free to accept it as answer :) if not, i can help answer more questions